# Cypress+TS, how to get second text that wrapped double quotes?

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-each

I got this web page to test claim number. But I am not able to extract the same.

```
<h1 class="jss41 undefined" style="text-transform: capitalize; display: flex; align-items: center; margin-bottom: 0.5rem;">
"Claims #"
"75078"
</h1>
```

The xpath I am trying to get is

```
export const getClaimsHeader = () => cy.xpath("//h1[contains(@class,'undefined')]")
```

This is the code I am trying to get the claim Number

```
  getClaimsHeader()
  .each((header) => {
    claimNum = header.text().split('#');
    actualClaimNumber = claimNum[1];
    
  })
  .then(() => {
    expect(claimNumber).to.equal(actualClaimNumber);
  });
```

But `actualClaimNumber` is displayed as blank because `header.text()` is returning only "Claims #"

Comment: How are you extracting the inner text?

Comment: I updated the question, I missed to add text here in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have textNodes inside the `<h1>` although it's not apparent from the HTML.

If so, here is a function to try out which should return all the textNodes in an array:

```js
function getTextNodes($el) {
  const childNodes = $el[0].childNodes
  const textNodes = [...childNodes].filter(child => child.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE)
  const texts = textNodes.map(textNode => textNode.nodeValue.trim())
  return texts
}
```

Use it like this

```js
getClaimsHeader().each((header) => {
  const texts = getTextNodes(header);
  console.log(texts)              // check which part of the array is the number
  const claim = texts[1]          // for example
})
```

Since you're using `.each()` I presume there are multiple headers?

If so, your `.then()` does not receive each claim number, only the last one.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you nearly have it, but you would need to remove the double-quotes as well since they are part of the text.

Also add `trim()` to remove any linefeed that may be there.

Lastly, in your sample code `expect(claimNumber).to.equal(actualClaimNumber)` will never pass because `actualClaimNumber` is calculated from `claimNumber`

```js
const actualClaimNumbers = ['75078', ...];

getClaimsHeader()
  .each((header, index) => {
    const claimNumber = header.text().split('#')[1].replace(/"/g, '').trim()

    console.log('header text', claimNumber);

    expect(claimNumber).to.equal(actualClaimNumbers[index])
  })
```

Comment: I am trying to extract only actualClaimNumber. claimNumber is already declared above the code as const claimNumber = '75078'; I missed to mention the same in the code. Also, I updated the question. I apologized for the typo